# Value of a line integral

Tags: vector-analysis, line-integrals, greens-theorem

What is the value of the line integral  $\oint\limits_{C}(sin(y)dx+xcos(y)dy)$ , where C consists of the circle $x^2+y^2=2 $ from $(-1,1)$ to $(1,1)$ and the line segment from $(1,1)$ to $(-1,1)$?

**What I have done so far:**

Using Green's Theorem I have $$\oint\limits_{C}(sin(y)dx+xcos(y)dy)= \iint\limits_{\Omega}2cos(y)dxdy$$

However I don't know what the limits should be for the integrals.

Comment: Are you sure you are doing integrals over line segments or are you doing it over the arc?

Comment: @Rox If the field is conservative, that line integral will be zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have incorrectly done Greens.

$P= \sin(y)$
$ Q = x \cos(y)$

$$ \frac{ \partial Q}{\partial x} = \cos(y)$$

$$ \frac{ \partial P}{\partial y} =  \cos(y)$$

Now greens say:

$$ \oint Pdx + Qdy = \int \frac{ \partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} dA= \int 0 dA$$

**Comment:**

The line integral being zero for any loop is equivalent to field being conservative, for any loop we could have done the green's conversion is zero, hence the criteria for if vector field is conservative or not is that the:

$$ \frac{ \partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{ \partial P}{\partial y} = 0$$

As mentioned by @PierreCarre

Comment: Feeling something fishy..

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I kept slamming numbers into integral calculator and I kept getting weird answers then I realized the application of greens was wrong in your q

Comment: Oh whoops my bad yes it should be a minus. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If C is any simple closed piecewise-smooth curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a line integral over C always $0$?

Comment: Assuming the ~~field is irrotational~~ the partial derivative difference thing is zero, yes

Comment: Basically this 2-d green is say that the line integral of vector field = area integral of curl

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/greens-theorem-and-stokes-theorem/greens-theorem-articles/a/greens-theorem?modal=1

See article of greens theorem here, they explain it using the curl formalism which I think is more intuitive

Answer (score 0):

The vector field $(\sin y, x \cos y)$ is conservative. You can check this by noting that $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$. So, the value of the integral will be independent from the path and, in particular, if you end up returning to the starting point, the integral is zero.

Comment: Thank you! So I should always check first if the vector field is conservative?

Comment: If C is any simple closed piecewise-smooth curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a line integral over C always $0$?

Comment: @Rox If you are integrating a conservative field, yes.